# Error in regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am a beginner in python, and when I am running following regex, it is getting stuck on my mac:

```
re.search("^[A-Z]+([A-Z\w]+|\s)+$","Diploma in Fine Art from Royal School of Art & Design")
```

Please let me know if I am doing any mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting stuck"?  Does it run at all?  Do you get an error?  Do you get unexpected output?

Comment: It means catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I was not able to get any answer after running that command. Thanks Wiktor for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The regex is written in such a way that it can easily cause a catastrophic backtracking issue, namely, the `([A-Z\w]+|\s)+` part is causing that issue because of the nested `+` quantifier. You must be looking for a

```
^[A-Z][a-z]*(\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gI8qC5/3)

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` - one uppercased word
- `(\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)+` - one or more uppercased ASCII words separated with whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Hint: always test your patterns against non-matching patterns (like yours) since they are the most problematic.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I was trying to write a regex which matches with sequence of words in which each word has capital letter (e.g. "Royal School").